# What is proper way to calling session_start()

Tags: php

I have two shared host.
my problem is realated with calling session_start().
In my localhost and one of my shared host. session start works well with user notice that : cannot call header. then i used to write the below code:

```
<?php
if(! isset($_SESSION)){
 session_start()
}
?>
```

But in another host, it still echo message that **"Notice: cannot start session()..."**
also my problem that session doesn't starts in first visit. When I refresh my browser window again then starts session. what is relation between client and server side. again what is wrong with my session_start() ? please help me.

May anyone tell me that what is the proper way to calling a session_start() which will never fail. and where should I call. very top of the page or anywhere in the configuration file. a little example will help me surely.

Comment: What is the full output of the error ? It seems your script is already sending data before session_start()

Answer (score 8):

Two simple things:

**1. Always call `session_start` unconditionally.**

**2. Always call `session_start` before you output anything on the page.**

So you should do it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// and now anything else
```

In particular, be aware that you can violate directive #2 in many different ways, e.g. by:

- Explicitly printing anything yourself with `echo` etc.
- Having *any characters at all* in your PHP script before the `<?php` tag
- Inlcuding other scripts that do the above

There are [lots and lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers%20already%20sent) here on SO that describe point #2 and how to solve it.

Comment: If you're not planning on changing session variables and your session management system with apache is file based always call session_write_close();