# Pass jscolor from one php page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jscolor

I'm using jscolor and trying to pass the users selected color from `test1.php` to `test2.php` and then convert to rgb. Somehow is not working.

If I change the form post to `test1.php` it retrieves the correct value, but when changing `action="test2.php"` then is not working.

test1.php:

```
<script>
function update(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor
}
</script>

 <form action="test2.php" method="post">
     Select you favorite color:
     <input name="clr1" class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}">
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
 <p id="rect" style="border:1px solid gray; width:161px; height:100px;">

<?php 
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['clr1'])) { 
      $selected_color = $_POST['clr1']; 
      $_SESSION['bgcolors'] = $selected_color;
  }
?>
```

test2.php:

```
session_start();
$selected_color = $_SESSION['bgcolors'];
echo $selected_color;
echo "<br>";
list($r, $g, $b) = array_map('hexdec', str_split($selected_color, 2));

$bgcolor2 = $r . "," . $g . "," .$b;
echo $bgcolor2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in `test2.php` after `session_start` this code

```
 if (isset($_POST['clr1'])) { 
    $selected_color = $_POST['clr1']; 
    $_SESSION['bgcolors'] = $selected_color;
 }
```

Comment: Omg, my code was actually fine which I'm amazed, I just needed to move it. Works great, thank you. Would you please help me understand the logic of what I was doing wrong please? I thought $_POST was needed to get the data from the form (in the same page where the form is), but I didn't know the form data was actually passed to the action .php, otherwise I don't know how is getting 'clr1' in test2.php

Comment: Browser sends data to route (in your case `test2.php`) which assigned in action field of form.

Comment: Thank you very much potiev, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

In php page 2 you are going to want to retrieve the variable by starting the session with session_start and after that you can access it with $_SESSION['bgcolors']

However I can see a problem with your code in that you are not calling session_start the first think you do.

> Always call session_start unconditionally.
>   Always call session_start before you output anything on the page.

As seen in this stack response [What is proper way to calling session_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455063/what-is-proper-way-to-calling-session-start)

Comment: Both pages, test1.php and test2.php have session_start(); at the first php line

Comment: Yes but that section of php code would have to be located above any type of HTML in the document.